# Display image in laravel 7

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I store an image with

```
$cat->picture = $request->file('catpicture')->store('public/catpictures');
$cat->save();
```

I do a ls in "/var/www/html/project/storage/app/public/catpictures", the image is saved

I created the symlink

```
php artisan storage:link
The [/var/www/html/project/public/storage] link has been connected to [/var/www/html/project/storage/app/public].
The links have been created.
```

In my blade I have:

```
<img src="{{url($cat->picture)}}" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Responsive image">
```

which is "public/catpictures/IgTx81OYKVymthuzTydFVepGvFZGALeeW1FmHpas.png"

The image doesnt show,what am I missing?
The src is http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/catpictures/IgTx81OYKVymthuzTydFVepGvFZGALeeW1FmHpas.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `url`, better to use `asset` to retrieve asset

Actually you don't need to add `public` prefix in your `store()` function. When you call `store()`, it will use the path from `config/filesystems.php`. The path will be taken from the `default disks`.

[Asset vs Url](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/asset-vs-url)

```
<img src="{{asset('/storage/' . $cat->picture)}}" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Responsive image">
```

Comment: Same src as above.

Comment: Thanks,it gives this http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/public/catpictures/IgTx81OYKVymthuzTydFVepGvFZGALeeW1FmHpas.png. If I remove public,it works.Should I edit the save path or is there a function?I dont want to do string manipulation.

Comment: you can use `Storage::disk('public')` to save in your `storage/app/public` folder

Comment: but it's up to you, I thought that `store()` method depends on `config/filesystems.php` default configuration, where the file will store. So, you don't need to add `public` in your path.

Comment: I change ` 'root' => storage_path('app/public'),` from `'root' => storage_path('app'),`  So i dont need to add public to save path.Thanks.

Comment: Pleasure. Happy coding!